Пунктуация в прямой речи, выделение слов автора
Интересует вопрос правильной пукнтуации в прямой речи, особенно оформление слов автора в диалогах. У Розенталя говорится так:


Если слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение, то они пишутся с прописной буквы.
— Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.


Однако пример всего один, а ситуаций может быть много разных. Например, у меня есть две фразы:


— Пожалуй. — Она вновь улыбнулась. — Очень хорошо, что ты так думаешь.
— Ничего, — улыбнулась Маша.


Из художественной литературы примерно понял, что с маленькой буквы слова автора начинаются в том случае, если дальше будет пояснение к речи героя с глаголами в духе "сказал", "ответил", "воскликнул" и т.п. Однако если в приведенных выше примерах в 1. еще можно сказать, что "слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, представляют собой отдельное предложение", то в 2. "улыбнулась Маша" явно на отдельное предложение не тянет.
Или вот, например:


— Да уже все знают! Я, кстати, Леший. Можешь меня так и звать, — протянул он мне руку.


Опять же, слабо представляю, что "протянул он мне руку" можно написать с нового абзаца.
Мой вопрос состоит в следующем: как понять и поймать ту грань, когда слова автора - это "отдельное предложение", а когда нет?

Dreamtale, теперь вы можете не только принимать ответы на свои вопросы галочкой, но и отмечать все полезные ответы и вопросы стрелочкой вверх. Спрашивайте, отвечайте, успехов!


ТЕОРИЯ

В этой теме важно различать атрибуцию (слова автора, приписывание) и авторскую речь.
Атрибуция  обычно содержит атрибутивные глаголы со значением мысли или чувства (подумал, сказал) и близкие к ним. Эти глаголы делятся на три группы: атрибутивные, условно-атрибутивные и неатрибутивные (описание действий говорящего).
Атрибуция записывается со строчной буквы, так как не является самостоятельным предложением. Порядок слов обычно инверсионный: сказал он, а не он сказал.  Атрибуция не переносится  на новый абзац.
Авторская речь описывает действия персонажа и противопоставлена атрибуции. Это самостоятельное предложение, которое пишется с прописной буквы; порядок слов прямой. Авторская речь переносится на новый абзац, но допускается отсутствие переноса.

ПРАКТИКА

Авторская речь:
   — Пожалуй. — Она вновь улыбнулась. — Очень хорошо, что ты 
   так думаешь.  

Атрибуция.  Условно-атрибутивный глагол:
    — Ничего, — улыбнулась Маша. 

Здесь авторская речь, которая имеет варианты, например:
  — Да уже все знают! Я, кстати, Леший. Можешь меня так и 
  звать.
   Он протянул мне руку. 

   — Да уже все знают! Я, кстати, Леший. — Он протянул мне 
   руку. — Можешь меня так и звать.

СТАТЬИ ПО ТЕМЕ (желательно прочитать, полезный материал)

Атрибуция в диалогах

Содержание
• Что такое атрибуция
• Зачем нужна атрибуция
• Какие глаголы использовать﻿
• Как не повторяться
• Можно ли обойтись без атрибуции?

​ Атрибуция. Авторская речь. Пунктуация в диалогах. Л. Ситникова.

В статье  рассказано об отличии авторской речи от атрибуции. Дана сравнительная таблица.

Вопрос: Авторская речь в первом варианте может же находиться сразу за прямой, а не в новом абзаце?

О, какие люди! А я собираюсь отвечать автору вопроса) Теоретически может, да, но мне не нравится этот вариант с точки зрения эстетики) Захотелось жест отделить от предыдущей реплики. Поэтому я решила перенести предложение на новый абзац или выбрать второй вариант (он мне кажется наилучшим). А первый надо бы проверить по реальным текстам, то есть когда такое оформление выглядит уместным. –

Но ведь мы же с вами тоже создаём реальные тексты... Думаю, такое оформление может выглядеть уместно, тем более не противоречит правилам. Дело за автором текста, как он хочет его представить.

Я вас понял, спасибо. В третьем примере вы предложили два варианта, как можно перестроить предложение. Но интересно все-таки, как написать правильно, если оставить все так, как у меня изначально:
— Да уже все знают! Я, кстати, Леший. Можешь меня так и звать, — протянул он мне руку.

Думаю, что нет.  Это неатрибутивный глагол. В статье такие примеры названы ошибочными. Но это всего лишь статья, а не официальные правила. Главное, надо понимать  теорию, которую нам предлагают как обобщение практики и делать свой выбор. То есть вы должны считать этот глагол условно-атрибутивным, если так пишете.  Кроме того,  мне не нравится, что атрибуция идет после нескольких предложений.  Странно выглядит.

@Александр Стрелец
Я имела в виду, что не мешает проверять свое решение по художественной литературе, которую правили профессиональные редакторы-корректоры. А я всего лишь поясняю правила так, как их понимаю. // Но вы, кажется, не стали бы переносить, и это ваш выбор.  Текст должен смотреться красиво и уместно, это важно. // Но, возможно, вы иначе понимаете правила?  Пусть все пишут по образцу: — Скорей, загорелась школа! — И он побежал по домам будить людей.

@Sharon
Ну хорошо, это я в целом понял. Остался момент с условно-атрибутивными глаголами. То есть таковыми могут быть не только глаголы "говорения", но и глаголы эмоций, так сказать? Например, "улыбнулась"?

— Ничего, — улыбнулась Маша. //  Да, это выражение эмоций, хотя не прямой глагол говорения. В статье даны примеры таких глаголов. Вот еще материал по глаголам  https://ficwriter.info/stati/321-kak-napisat-knigu-q/metody-i-priemy/7770-govoritelnye-glagoly-v-dialogakh.html/

@Sharon Выбор я не делал, т.к. переносить или не переносить – решать корректору-редактору в содружестве с автором. Их выбор будет влиять на состояние литературы в данный период. // Поддерживаю ваш ответ и мнение на счёт атрибутивности.

@Александр Стрелец Так сделайте свой выбор, мне интересно ваше решения. Я обычно доверяла вашему вкусу, хотя, признаться, меня огорчило то, то вам не нравится оформление моих ответов.

@Sharon Чтобы выбрать, нужно спросить у автора текста о возможности менять структуру предложений. Мне больше нравится ваш второй вариант, с разбивкой прямой речи. При таком порядке, наверно, может появиться возможность атрибуции с инверсией и отнесение "протянул руку" непосредственно к словам знакомства "Я, кстати, Леший". // Оформление стало лучше и уже привычнее. Вы объяснили свою позицию насчёт невыделения необходимого в цитатах, и я это принял. Всё ок! (Про "не нравится" речи не было, я просто задавал вопросы.)

@Александр Стрелец Там ничего не надо менять, просто включить авторскую речь в абзац. //Думаю, что нет.  Такие глаголы вне атрибуции. Так редактор из статьи считает, ну и мне так кажется.

@Sharon Но там вы поменяли порядок слов на прямой, то есть уже не так, как написал изначально автор. // Насчёт атрибуции сейчас вспомнил, что если к глаголу можно присоединить глагол говорения, то первый может стать глаголом, вводящим прямую речь, и появляется двоеточние. Он протянул руку [и сказал]: "Я Карлсон!" (короче, размышляю)

Про двоеточие свой разговор... Не стоит в одной теме стараться объять необъятное. Я тоже помню это правило. Речь идет о глаголах, вводящих прямую речь,  а не об атрибутивных глаголах. Мать нахмурилась (и спросила):
— Опять двойку получил?
